# What is the difference between thermodynamical equilibrium and statistical equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am trying to understand what is the different between thermodynamical equilibrium and statistical equilibrium, for example, between photons and electrons at the early universe.
(I read through paper http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9705101, where I have encountered this distinction at page 3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Statistical Equilibrium:** That state of a closed statistical system in which the average values of all the physical quantities characterizing the state are independent of time. In other words when systems do not evolve in time i.e. when they are in steady state.

In **thermodynamic equilibrium** there are no net macroscopic flows of matter or of energy, either within a system or between systems. In a system in its own state of internal thermodynamic equilibrium, no macroscopic change occurs. Systems in mutual thermodynamic equilibrium are simultaneously in mutual thermal, mechanical, chemical, and radiative equilibria. Systems can be in one kind of mutual equilibrium, though not in others. In thermodynamic equilibrium, all kinds of equilibrium hold at once and indefinitely, until disturbed by a thermodynamic operation.