# Regarding the relation between statistical equilibrium and thermal equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, equilibrium

I've seen a similar set of questions on the topic in SE but none seem to satisfy me.So,the question is as follows:1)What is the relation between thermodynamic equilibrium and statistical equilibrium for a microcanonical system?
2)Is statistical equilibrium a necessary condition for thermal equilibrium?Is it sufficient?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98065/what-is-the-difference-between-thermodynamical-equilibrium-and-statistical-equil

Comment: @JánLalinský My question is not about their individual definitions but of their relation and if they are both equivalent

Comment: You can deduce most of that from the definitions in that answer by @aritra, see my answer below.

Comment: What is statistical equilibrium?

Comment: @TobiasFünke Reif in his book defines it as a situation where all microstates have equal probability of occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation is that in statistical physics, expected averages are used in the role of values of thermodynamic quantities, to describe/illuminate equilibrium states of classical thermodynamics (that theory about work, heat, heat capacities, heat engines, entropy and so on, that does not use probabilistic notions). It is one possible and powerful viewpoint on what the details behind the macroscopic notions of thermodynamics are.

In statistical physics, probability distributions obeying statistical equilibrium is a necessary condition for describing both thermal and thermodynamic equilibrium. Description of these kinds of equilibrium requires that physical quantities are constant in time, thus expected averages are constant in time, thus functions have to obey the condition of statistical equilibrium.

Statistical equilibrium is sufficient for describing thermal equilibrium (constant values of physics quantities), but not for thermodynamic equilibrium (which in addition requires zero energy flux everywhere).

Comment: Are the average values of the physical quantities characterizing the state what we observe macroscopically when we perform experiments?sorry if this qn is bit off topic

Comment: That is the assumption of statistical physics, used to work out the theory, but it is not really true, because getting an average takes either a very long time, or very many copies of the system, and experiments take finite, often very short time, and work on single system.

Comment: Then how does average quantities being constant in time ensure that macroscopic quantities specifying state also remain constant in time?

Comment: The calculated average being constant in time is really a constraint on the applicable probability distributions, in statistical physics, for them to be admissible for description of a thermodynamic system whose state variables maintain well-defined constant values in time. Statistical physics does not ensure that actual macroscopic systems remain constant in time, only that the probability distribution remains consistent with that fact which we assume to be true based on experience - if conditions allow, a system settles in an equilibrium macroscopic state and does not leave it on its own.